# Is it possible to have an "Always on top" feature in (L)ubuntu?

Tags: window-manager, openbox

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 64 Bit and I need to have the "Always on top" feature so I can have any window always visible if I need to.

I've searched a lot up and down, but to my surprise I could not find anything.

Is it possible at all to have this feature ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved!

> Right-click the Window Decoration (Upper Window Border) => Layer => Always
>   on top

Credit goes to "drooly" at the [LXDE forums](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=37084)

Comment: Another way to do this is using the keyboard shortcut alt+space to bring up the same menu then select always on top.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the command line when opening a GUI program in Lubuntu 14.04?

Comment: the alt+space @ianorlin mentioned is important to override Chrome's right click menu